# (ColdFusion) Compare two dates, use result to determine what displays

Tags: coldfusion

I'm working on a client's site, and he needs coupon expiration dates to change red if they're two weeks or less to expiring. Otherwise they will be black.

The site itself was not made by me. I just started here and they want me to learn ColdFusion. So I've been stumbling through it.

I thought that maybe by using [DateCompare](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#datecompare) or [DateDiff](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#datediff) I could get what I want. However I get garbled text when I `<CFOUTPUT>` the results of either comparison. It displays a long string of `51515151551` that gradually gets smaller and smaller for each subsequent coupon item on the customers list.

The coupon date itself (ie end_date) is called from the Microsoft SQL database. It is formatted using Dateformat: `#dateformat(end_date,"m/d/yyyy")#`.

I tried to compare it with `Now()` in order to dynamically determine whether or not the expiration date should be colored red. I've also tried formatting `Now()`, I get the same results.

Any seasoned programmers here that could lead me to the right path?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Datediff is what you want. Are you using the correct date part in date diff? You could use 'ww' for weeks or 'd' for days, I used days in the below example.

```
<cfset CouponDate = createDate( 2012, 05, 29 ) />
<cfif DateDiff( "d", CouponDate, Now() ) GTE 14>
    <cfset Expired = False />
<cfelse>
    <cfset Expired = True />
</cfif>
```

Obviously you don't need to set a variable or anything, this is just some example code to get your idea working. :)

Comment: Yeah, what he said, verbatim. :)

Comment: I think the `expired` values are reversed.

Comment: They are! Fixing... I switched it up so CouponDate was first then Now() and didn't swap them around too. Good catch.

Comment: Hrm, I'm looking into this solution right now. This is great! It's good to know that I wasn't far off from the answer.

I love stackoverflow.

Comment: Be careful because datediff in Microsoft SQL Server and Adobe ColdFusion have a lot of similarities.

Comment: Seven years later, Datediff returns 2688 - still not expired 

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfscript>
// setup first test date for 7 days ago
date1 = dateAdd( 'd', -7, now() );
// setup second date for 14 days ago
date2 = dateAdd( 'd', -14, now() );
// compare date 1
writeOutput( dateDiff('d', date1, now() ) & '<hr/>');
// compare date 2
writeOutput( dateDiff('d', date2, now() )  & '<hr/>');
// demonstrate use
if ( dateDiff('d', date2, now()) gte 14 ) {
    writeOutput( 'RED' );
}
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<cfset dtdiff = query.expiry_date - Now() />
<cfif Round(dtdiff) LEQ 14>
    Red
<cfelse>
    Black
</cfif>
```

if you wan't to use 14 days with time difference you can use

`Fix(dtdiff)` instead of `Round(dtdiff)`

Comment: i had issue with comparing mssql timestamp to coldfusion Now(). with this i fixed the issue. and i am sure Stackoverflow expects diff answers.. and this may surely help others.

Comment: What kind of issue? (If you really mean `timestamp` that is totally different than date/datetime.) When it comes to dates, best not to roll-your-own logic unless there is a very good reason.

Comment: issue with diff between mssql timestamp and now. anyways different answers are encouraged in stackoverflow.